# Is this copy constructor elision?

Tags: c++, optimization, constructor, copy-elision

The following code doesn't call the copy constructor.

```
struct X
{
   int x;
   X(int num)
   {
      x = num;
      std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
   }
   X(const X& other)
   {
      std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
   }
};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   X* x = new X(3);
   X* y(x);
}
```

Output:

```
ctor
```

Is it copy-ctor elision?

Comment: I can't see a single copy that even could be elided. Are you sure your example is correct?

Comment: @CharlesBailey well `X(const X& other)` **could** be elided in the right context (which this isn't).

Comment: Please don't learn C++ with a Java book, it doesn't do anybody any good.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I don't believe there's a single copy of `X` being made in the whole example - candidate for elision or not. Have I missed something?

Comment: @CharlesBailey exactly. I think that's just a confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code

```
X* x = new X(3);
X* y(x);
```

is not the same as

```
X x(3);
X* y = new X(x);
```

**You're not copying objects, but pointers.** After `X* y(x);`, both pointers will point to the same object.